# Force EF6 scaffolder to include 'using' directives inside namespace

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When generating the Database Context class and POCO entity classes, using Scaffold-DbContext command (DB first approach) the classes are generated in following way:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace Database
    {
        public partial class User
        {
            public User()
            { ... }
        }
    }
```

What I want to achieve is to have the POCO classes generated with 'using' directives inside the namespace, like this:

```
    namespace Database
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class User
        {
            public User()
            { ... }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to achieve without modification of EF T4 templates?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method that reads the lines of POCO files, detects the `using` lines, removes them and re-write them under the `namespace` line.

This can be achieved by using a T4 template. Run this template on build every time to ensure that all POCO's are modified.

Example for a single model:

```
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<# 
string path = this.Host.ResolvePath(@"PocoClass.cs");
var PocoLines= File.ReadLines(path).ToArray();

List<string> usingStatements = new List<string>();

foreach (var line in pocoLines)
{
    if(Regex.Match(line, "RegexForUsings") //or use String.Contains("using");
        usingStatements.Add(line);
}
//insert lines again in PocoLines
#>
```